# Loading all rows from database efficiently (Content Provider, RecyclerView)

Tags: java, android, database

I'm pretty new to Android Developemnt. Currently, I am developing some sort of "funny images manager" (just simple app to practice), I created simple DB which stores:
-Name of file
-path to the file (I didn't want to store images as BLOBs as images may be potentially quite large)
-some sort of additional information
I have also a fragment which displays all images (it loads all rows) - it's a RecyclerView.

Currently I made something like:
The fragments fetches all data from DB using contentResolver (additionally I have contentProvider) as follows:

```
private void fetchDataFromDb(){


    //uri for  query for the  whole Table 
    Uri uri= DatabaseDescription.Picture.CONTENT_URI;

    //query for ContentResolver
    //TODO warning: passing null as projection is unefficient - returns all columns ( from docs -> I want that though)

    Cursor cursor=contentResolver.query(uri,null,null,null,null,null);

    while(cursor.moveToNext()){
        // my strange fetching from cursor
        String path=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseDescription.Picture.COLUMN_PIC_PATH));
        String name=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseDescription.Picture.COLUMN_PIC_NAME));
        String fileName=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseDescription.Picture.COLUMN_FNAME));
        String description=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseDescription.Picture.COLUMN_DESCRIPTION));

        funnyImagesList.add(new MyFunnyImg(path,name,description,fileName));
    }
}
```

MyFunnyImg is a class describing images - it contains of name, path and so on
funnyImagesList is a List (ArrayList) which stores all images (as objects of MyFunnyImg class) and it is passed to RecyclerViewAdapter in order to load proper images in onBindViewHolder method (using method from MyFunnyImg class - method below)

onBindViewHolder method:

```
 public void onBindViewHolder(RecycleAdapterImage.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    String description=argsToShow.get(position).getDescription();
    Bitmap image=argsToShow.get(position).loadBitmap(activity);
    String name=argsToShow.get(position).getName();



    CardView cardView=holder.cardView;
    ImageView imageView=(ImageView)cardView.findViewById(R.id.picture);
    imageView.setImageBitmap(image);
    TextView textView=(TextView)cardView.findViewById(R.id.card_view_des);
    textView.setText(description);//description
}
```

load method from MyFunnyImg:

```
public Bitmap loadBitmap(Activity activity){

    //String root= Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();


    //TODO change this strange structure
    String root=null;
    try {
         root = activity.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES).toString();
    }catch(NullPointerException ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
        Log.e("Error","NullPointerException while loeadin BitMap");
    }




    File dir=new File(root+"/saved_images");

    Bitmap bitmap=null;

    Log.i("Loading",fileName);
    File file=new File(dir, fileName);

    if (activity.checkSelfPermission(android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        Log.i("Info","Asking for permission to read if not granted yet");
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity,new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},4200);
    }else {

        try {
            FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(file);
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
            if(bitmap==null)Toast.makeText(activity,"In RecyclerView bitmap is null1",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

            Log.e("Error:", "Error while reading an image");
        }
    }

    if(bitmap==null)Toast.makeText(activity,"In RecyclerView bitmap is null2",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    return bitmap;
}
```

I know that there may be some "terrifying" constructions but I will fix them later. My question is - how to do the same thing more efficient? I was reading about threads in background and so one (maybe there is some in my code but I don't know it???) and want to do it as much efficient as I can (now I feel like my app is lagging when I enter this fragment - even though there are 2/3 images there...).

Comment: Guys please help I have run with problems with memory already :((

Comment: Example error:(contacted to the memory)Process: com.example.tomek.gallery, PID: 19187
                  java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 52833036 byte allocation with 16777216 free bytes and 31MB until OOM
                      at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)